# Cannot read in a txt file using ifstream

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am trying to read in a basic txt file, but I think the programming is not detecting the txt file. Here's my code.

```
int main() {
   ifstream in;
   in.open("testing.txt");
   if (in.fail()) cout << "fail" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The program is printing out fail. I created the txt file by right clicking the project and adding a new empty file. I am completely stuck, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try using the full file path instead of using just the file name.

Comment: Probably the program is running in a different directory as where the file is stored. Did you try it with a full filepath?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It worked. How can I make it so that I only need to say "testing.txt" instead of "C:\\Users\\nathan\\workspace\\C++\\Practice\\scores.txt"? Thanks

Comment: @NathanKou Open a console, change to the directory _`"C:\Users\nathan\workspace\C++\Practice"`_, and run your program from there.

Comment: I know how to get there from the console, but how do I run the program from there?

Comment: @NathanKou _"but how do I run the program from there?"_ Well, the operating system either needs to see either the path were it resides in the `PATH` system variable, or you have to specify the full path of the program.

Comment: Relative paths are opened relative to the programs `current working directory`, so make sure that is correct. Checking is easy, just use the `getcwd()` function to see what it currently is and `chdir()` to change it - or change (in your IDE) what the CWD is when launching the executable.

Comment: @m.s. I'm not a 100% sure that your edit (removing the relevance of OtCreator IDE) was legit. It could well be the OP just wants (needs) to know how to change their project settings in the IDE, where the executable artifact should be run from the IDE.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you might be right, I re-added the qt-creator tag

Answer (score 1):

As from QT Creator's documentation, you can change the working directory where your program should be executed in the [project run settings](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html):

[image]

If your file exists in a different path than the default (which is where QT Creator builds the executable), you can set it there.

> I created the txt file by right clicking the project and adding a new empty file.

That creates the `.txt` file at your project main path, not where the executable is build actually.